# How do I configure the search domain correctly?

Tags: networking, network-manager, 14.10, dns

I recently installed Ubuntu GNOME on my work computer, replacing Windows 7, because I will be doing a lot of Linux development work.

Many of our configuration and development scripts use shortened URLs for servers on the company network. That is, they use `http://server` rather than `http://server.location.company.com`. I never had problems with these URLS in Windows, but I have not been able to get them to work correctly in Ubuntu. It is not feasible for me to simply type the entire fully-qualified URL because the shortened form is used all over the place in various scripts, but I am able to access the long-form URLs.

When I connect to the company's VPN using the [Dell SonicWall NetExtender VPN Client](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/en/products/324.html), the shortened URLS do work correctly.

Based on the research I have done so far, I think that I need to configure `location.company.com` as a search domain on Ubuntu, but my attempts at doing this have failed so far. Here is what I have tried:

- In the "Network Connections" app, edit my wireless connection. Under the IPv4 tab, select Automatic (DHCP) addresses only. Then type in `location.company.com` as a search domain, and put our DNS server in as well. This made no noticeable difference.
- Modifying dhclient.conf as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52001/adding-additional-dns-search-domains-when-using-dhcp).
- Running `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` to make sure that it dynamically updates resolv.conf.

I am also worried that at this point I have tried several different things and they could be interfering with each other. I know that some parts of this configuration changed in the last couple of years with Ubuntu, and it can be hard to find the most current information. It is not completely clear to me how network-manager, resolvconf, dhclient, and other configuration files work together in the newest versions of Ubuntu.

So, my question: How can I configure my computer to make the short-form URLs work correctly in Ubuntu 14.10?

Or, which network configuration programs should I be using to do this, how should I configure them, and how can I verify that they are working correctly?

Thanks for your help! Let me know if I can provide any additional info.

Edit: Here is my `/etc/resolv.conf`, which I believe was generated by resolvconf.

```
# Add Company Nameservers and Domain
nameserver 192.168.200.53
nameserver 192.168.200.65
search location.company.com
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search location.company.com
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search hsd1.co.comcast.net
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Quick Update: At some point I did a clean install of a more recent version of Ubuntu. Maybe 16.04? Anyway, I haven't had any issues and haven't had to reconfigure anything since then, and I'm now on 18.10.

Answer (score 45):

Search domain means the domain that will be automatically appended when you only use the hostname for a particular host or computer. This is basically used in a local network.

Lets say you have a domain name like `xyz.com` (it may be available globally or may be local only) and you have 100 computers in the LAN. Now you want this domain name to be automatically appended when you look for any computer by just hostname of the computer. If the domain name to be appended is `xyz.com` then the search domain should look like:

```
dns-search xyz.com ##If you put this into /etc/network/interfaces
```

or

```
search xyz.com ##If you put this into /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base|head|tail
```

Now how do you check if its working properly, just use `ping` or any DNS resolving program like `host`, `nslookup` , `dig`.

For example if a host is `test` having the IP `192.168.1.5` then using `host`:

```
host test
test.xyz.com has address 192.168.1.5
```

Now as `dig` does not use the search list/domain by default you need to use it like `dig +search test` to enable appending search domain.

Using `nslookup`:

```
nslookup test
Server:     192.168.1.11
Address:    192.168.1.11#53

Name:   test.xyz.com
Address: 192.168.1.5
```

Here `192.168.1.11` is your local DNS server which has the IP address for the host `test.xyz.com` (notice the full form) that is `192.168.1.5`. The DNS server will resolve the hostname `test.xyz.com` to IP `192.168.1.5` but will not resolve anything for only `test` as it does not have any entry like so.

So, what search domain is doing in our case is that it is automatically appending a domain name to make it a FQDN when we are just using the hostname to look up a computer.

Comment: by default dig doesn't auto append the domain stuff like the other do. However, "dig +search test" does.

Comment: @DougSmythies: added..

Comment: I modified `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` with nameserver and search entries. I'm now seeing the following behavior: 
`$ host server`
server.location.company.com is an alias for server001.location.company.com.
server001.location.company.com has address 192.168.200.103
`$ ping server`
ping: unknown host server.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @mkasberg: Certain portion is missing in your last message..also note that after making any change in `resolvconf` run `sudo resolvconf -u`.

Comment: @mkasberg: Put it in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`..You DNS server has the entry for `server.location.company.com`, right?

Comment: Putting it in `head` and running `sudo resolvconf -u` seems to have no effect. `host` has the same output and `ping` still doesn't work. I *can* `ping server.location.company.com` so I know the FQDN works correctly. I don't understand why host would work but ping wouldn't, and I'm stuck because I have no idea how to "debug" this type of thing.

Comment: @mkasberg: Comment out (disable) the entries regarding `server` from your `/etc/hosts` file..

Comment: There are no lines regarding `server` in my /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Please post your `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: @mkasberg: Keep the first three lines while commenting out the rest of the entries in the `resolv.conf`. You better disable the entries from `network-manager` rather than directly editing the file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about needing `dig +search` to use the suffix.

Comment: While the information in this answer provided more information about what "search" domains are, it did not answer the question about how to configure the system to add search domains to resolve a host that was given without a domain.

Answer (score 38):

I'm running Bionic Beaver and my `resolv.conf` says:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
```

so my solution was to edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, option `Domains=` according to [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/resolved.conf.html)
and then restart systemd-resolved:

```
systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Comment: `systemctl` syntax is COMMAND [UNIT] order so this should be `systemctl restart systemd.resolved`

Comment: Not quite @karatedog , should be `systemctl restart systemd-resolved` or `systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia You are right, I focused on solely the order and missed the dash instead of the dot.

Answer (score 19):

I was looking for a solution to this issue for **Ubuntu Focal 20.04**, as my local domain was not appending to hostnames.

On most unix-like OS like Solaris, Debian, etc. the solution is to add a line with '`search domain.name`' to `/etc/resolv.conf` but modern Ubuntu releases use `systemd-resolved` now, so I had to figure out what to do.

Thankfully, it's still only one line - just using the `resolvectl` command now instead of editing a text file:

```
# resolvectl domain <ifname> domain.name
```

(you can find your `ifname` by invoking `ip addr` or `resolvectl status`)

*Note:  This change is not permanent, for a permanent solution please see the update below*

To verify it's working, make sure domain is listed by `systemd-resolved` by invoking:

```
user@host:/$ resolvectl status | tail

DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.2
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.2
                      192.168.1.3
          **DNS Domain: domain.name**
```

and that it's in the auto-generated `/etc/resolv.conf` by invoking:

```
user@host:/$ tail /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
**search domain.name**
```

And try `ssh` or `http` using a hostname instead of a FQDN to see if the configured local domain resolves automatically.

I think my solution is the easiest and least confusing option - it's probably worth at least trying first in case it works for you before exploring the solutions posed in other answers.

*Update 2-20-2020:*

I noticed this change is not permanent.  As per this question [DNS set to systemd's 127.0.0.53 - how to change permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently) I learned that the permanent configuration is stored in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` - just uncomment `Domains=` and write your domain in there:

```
[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
Domains=domain.name
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

Comment: @AveryFreedman Thank you so much for that update. It finally gave me a couple pieces of information that were missing in configuring my own network. It took me 9 months to get local DNS resolution working. I've done network administration for several decades and this level of difficulty is one of the reasons Linux will not replace Windows - Linux is still pretty user-unfriendly.

Comment: Good point about resolved.conf, but what's the magic command to apply the configuration change? I tried with a drop-in file in /etc/resolved.conf.d/, but not sure what's the incantation.

Answer (score 9):

From 16.04 on, the **Advanced Network Configuration** tool is only accessible via the command line:

`sudo nm-connection-editor`

The search domain can be configured on the `IPvX Settings` tab.

[image]

For further details, see [Thomas Ward's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068467/how-to-set-domain-search-on-ubuntu-18-04#1082634).

Answer (score 1):

In my case,
Adding search domain under /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
And restarting network manager
And restarting my VPN worked.

Issue I was facing was, that my Org provided custom DNS that was not accessible.

Solution:

Add
`search my.orgdomain.com`
in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail

After saving run
`sudo service network-manager restart`

Restart VPN